# Cannot Sync Axis In Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to the Tableau Software.  I have version 8.2.3 installed.  I'm trying to create a Network Chart via the example at:

http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2012/12/build-network-graphs-in-tableau.html

Seems simple enough.  They even provide the sample Excel workbook at:

Download Network Graphs Example Data (Microsoft Excel 2007/2010, 14.3K)

As I go through the example everything seems fine til I get to the part where it says:

---

Step 2 – Dual Axis

Add the “Circle Y” to View on the rows shelf as a double axis, and synchronize the two Y axes (right click on the axis, and click on “Synchronize axis”).

---

For some reason the "Synchronize Axis" option is greyed out (disabled).  I Googled and an article said that it might be because the data types are different.  So I created calculated fields like they said but that didn't work.

It seems that no matter what I do the "Sychronize Axis" option will not enable?  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help me with this?  I have a project due on Monday and really need to get this example up and running.

Thanks Thanks Thanks So Much!

Comment: Ok great.  I got it to work.  needed to click on "Dual Axis" first.     I have another problem.  They refer to "Label Pill" in the article.  I have to drag the "Node Name Field" to it.  What in the world is the "Label Pill"?

Comment: Look on the marks card for a square labelled "Label" and drop your field on it. The Label pill (aka shelf) shows or not depending on the mark type.

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because the data types on each axis are different. You can use INT() and FLOAT() on calculated fields in tableau to convert data types, or CAST with SQL to match datatypes.

AVG() will most likely produce a float and COUNT() will most likely produce an integer when using calculated fields in tableau.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too and talked to support. I've been able to fix it by casting both series as ints with INT() or FLOAT(). Since doing one didn't work, I'd try casting both fields. Another thing to try is to switch the order of the pills, then try again. Sometimes this strangely works.

http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_typeconversion.html

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the Y axis on the right side and select Fixed instead of Automatic and set the range exactly similar to the original y axis, it would align well.